# What does |, !, and & do outside of an if statement?

Tags: java

This may seem like a very noobish question, but I'v seen comparing symbols such as: `| ! &` outside of If Statements and have been wondering what it means, and how to use it. Most what I'v seen is setting variable such as `int = 1 | 2`. Thankyou.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: are u confusing `|` and `||`? `|` means a `bitwise-or` operation, and `||` is a logic or

Comment: @shengy Not true. `|` is logic or (applied to boolean operands), `||` is *conditional* logic or.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful links, I know it was a lame question, but I am still a leaning programmer, hints me coming to a community of helpful programmers willing to answer questions.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks~ my fault. Thought it was same in `C`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do exactly what they do inside `if`. Assuming a and b are both of type `boolean`:

1. `a | b` is true iff `a` or `b` is true (or both).
2. `a & b` is true iff `a` and `b` are both true.
3. !a is true iff a is false.

I suspect what's confusing you is the notion that expressions of type `boolean` can be treated as values just like `int` and `float`. There's nothing magical happening here, though. `boolean` is a type just like `int` and `float`. You can have `boolean` variables, `boolean` parameters, `boolean` fields and functions that return `boolean`.

Also note that, with boolean arguments, you are more likely to encounter `||` and `&&` than `|` and `&`. They are roughly the same, but exhibit short-circuit behaviour. For example, when evaluating the expression `f() || g()`, if `f()` returns true, the whole expression will evaluate to true and `g()` won't even be called since it won't affect the answer. This is faster if `g()` is slow, but also changes the meaning of the program if `g()` would have had side effects (like changing global state or printing to the console). In contrast, `f() | g()` evaluates `g()` no matter what `f()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Heard of bitwise operators? Yes they are the same.

Refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html